# [:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found]

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWdzY.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHvan.png)I am developing my application with flutter and firebase. In the application, you can log in with emial and password. When I extract the apk of the application and install it on my own phone or run it on the emulator, there is no problem, but when I install it on someone else's phone, I get the following error and I don't know how to solve it. But I couldn't solve it. Can you help me?

[firebase_auth/inknown]
An internal error has occurred
[:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found]

I couldn't try anything